# GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

I have created a cubeCamera that generates all the reflections for the materials of a few of my entities.

To make this a camera that can be accessed by any element that needs it, I made it global and am initializing it thru a custom component that is called once < a-scene> has loaded.

```
//<a-scene init-experience>
var cubeCamera
AFRAME.registerComponent('init-experience', {
    init: function(){
        cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 5000, 512 );
        cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
        cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( this.el.renderer, this.el.object3D );
        this.el.setObject3D('cube-camera', cubeCamera);
    },
    tick: function(){
        cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( this.el.sceneEl.renderer, this.el.sceneEl.object3D );
    }
});
```

That way, I can later create an object and just assign **cubeCamera.renderTarget;** to its **envMap**

All good up to there.

The problem is that once my scene loads and the **tick:function()** starts doing its thing, I get the following error:
**GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.**

Even with these errors, my scene runs on desktop and android, but crashes any browser on iOS.

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head, I'd look at three.js reflection envMap examples closely to see if there's any differences.

Comment: Were you able to figure something out on this issue with the cubeCamera?